# How to change the Nuxt 3 $fetch timeout limit of 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

It seems like the Nuxt 3 `$fetch` function has a 30 second timeout and I can't find a way to extend it. Is there a way to extend the timeout limit?

Example:

```
// server/api/render.ts
...
        var startTime = performance.now();
        try {
            const output = await $fetch(config.MODEL_ENDPOINT_URL + "/render", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(input),
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            var endTime = performance.now();

            console.log(
                "Execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000 // Throws error after exactly 30 seconds.
            );
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is implemented in [oFetch 1.2](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/releases/tag/v1.2.0) and use as `timeout` option. Nuxt 3.7 is using it!